# Radially symmetric SmoothHistogram3D?

Tags: linear-algebra, visualization

I have a sample from a distribution invariant w.r.t rotations around 0. What's the best way to incorporate this information into a smooth 3D histogram?

```
n = 400;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}];
products = NestList[sample . # &, sample, 2];
SmoothHistogram3D[ReIm /@ Eigenvalues[#], Axes -> False] & /@ products
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To account for the "known" radial symmetry about (0,0) first construct the (univariate) density of the distance from (0,0) and then transform to a 2-dimensional density.

```
(* Take a random sample from a radially symmetric distribution *)
n = 400;
SeedRandom[12345];
sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, 2}];

(* The usual nonparametric density estimate *)
skd2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[sample, "LeastSquaresCrossValidation"];

(* Accounting for the knowledge that the bivariate density is symmetric about {0,0} *)
d = Norm[#] & /@ sample; (* Distances from {0,0} *)
skd1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[d, 
   "LeastSquaresCrossValidation", {"Bounded", {0, ∞}, 
    "Gaussian"}];
(* To get the bivariate density estimate from the univariate density
   estimate divide by the circumference *)
pdf[x_, y_] := PDF[skd1, Norm[{x, y}]]/(2 π Norm[{x, y}])

(* Plot both bivariate density estimates *)
Plot3D[{PDF[skd2, {x, y}], pdf[x, y]}, {x, Min[sample], 
  Max[sample]}, {y, Min[sample], Max[sample]}, PlotTheme -> "ZMesh", 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 0.16}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Bivariate density estimates for basic nonparametric density and also accounting for radial symmetry about (0,0)]

Notice the funny business at (0,0).  Unless there are additional assumptions one can make, I think that will just be what one obtains.  (That happens from dividing by the distance from (0,0) which is close to zero near (0,0).)  For a justification for this approach (or maybe for a "Don't do it that way"), try asking this question at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: it looks like an alternative trick is just to add rotations of the data into the dataset

Comment: Rather than "trick", I would use tterms like "one more tool in the statistical toolbox" but I get your point.  Essentially the same thing can be done with samples from densities known to be symmetric about zero.

Comment: The following link has the same question at CrossValidated with links to solutions:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613725/kernel-density-estimation-on-2d-data-with-rotational-symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about getting the same bandwidth for each of the two dimensions in a nonparametric density estimator, then the following will do that:

```
n = 400;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}];
products = NestList[sample . # &, sample, 2];
data = ReIm /@ Eigenvalues[#] & /@ products;

(* Initial density *)
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[#, Automatic, {"Radial", "Gaussian"}] & /@ data;

(* Now use the average of the two automatically chosen bandwidths
  as the common bandwidth *)
skd2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data[[#]], 
  Mean[skd[[#, 2, 3]]] {1, 1}, {"Radial", "Gaussian"}] & /@ {1, 2,  3};

(* Plot results *)
Plot3D[PDF[skd2[[#]], {x, y}], {x, Min[data[[#]]], 
  Max[data[[#]]]}, {y, Min[data[[#]]], Max[data[[#]]]},
  PlotTheme -> "ZMesh", PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

[image: 3D smooth PDF's of the first 3 eigenvalues]

As a check that the same bandwidths are used for both dimensions:

```
skd[[1]]
```

[image: Summary of first pdf]

But if the data is invariant w.r.t. rotations around 0 *and* you have a large sample size, you won't see much difference from what you initially used and what I used above.

Comment: Underlying density is symmetric w.r.t rotations around 0, so the 3D histogram contours should be perfect circles

Comment: Thanks.  I clearly misunderstood the question.  In that case I would suggest that you only need a single and simpler example:  `sample = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, 2}];`.  And now to see that I really understand the question:  your question is analogous to a 1-dimensional sample where you want to estimate the density from a sample and incorporate the fact that you know the distribution is symmetric about zero but still use a nonparametric density estimator.

Comment: In fact, the approach should then probably be finding a nonparametric density for the distance from zero.  In other words, turning this into a 1-dimensional problem.